# Is it possible to write self referencing column in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, lag

I'm writing small poc trying to rewrite piece of logic written in python to pyspark, where im processing logs stored in sqlite one by one:

```
logs = [...]
processed_logs = []
previous_log = EmptyDecoratedLog() #empty
for log in logs:
    processed_log = with_outlet_value_closed(log, previous_log)
    previous_log = processed_log 
    processed_logs.append(processed_log)
```

and

```
def with_outlet_value_closed(current_entry: DecoratedLog, previous_entry: DecoratedLog):
    if current_entry.sourceName == "GS2":
        self.outletValveClosed = current_entry.eventData
    else:
        self.outletValveClosed = previous_entry.outletValveClosed
```

which I wanted to represent in pyspark api as:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
window = W.orderBy("ID") #where ID is unique id on those logs
df.withColumn("testValveOpened",
                f.when((f.col("sourceName") == "GS2"), f.col("eventData"))
                .otherwise(f.lag("testValveOpened").over(window)),
                )
```

but this leads to AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `outletValveClosed` cannot be resolved.

So my question is:
Is it possible to represent such code where the value of a current row depends from previous row of the same column(i know that this will result in all records being processed on a single thread, but thats fine)

I've tried adding initialization of a column

```
df = df.withColumn("testValveOpened", f.lit(0))
df.withColumn("testValveOpened",
                f.when((f.col("sourceName") == "GS2"), f.col("eventData"))
                .otherwise(f.lag("testValveOpened").over(window)),
                )
```

but then I'm getting

```
ID |sourceName|eventData|testValveOpened
1  |GS3       |1        |0
2  |GS2       |1        |1
3  |GS2       |8        |8
4  |GS1       |1        |0
5  |GS2       |2        |0
6  |ABC       |0        |0
7  |B123      |0        |0
8  |B423      |0        |0
9  |PTSD      |168      |0
10 |XCD       |0        |0
```

I would like to get

```
ID |sourceName|eventData|testValveOpened
1  |GS3       |1        |0
2  |GS2       |1        |1
3  |GS2       |8        |8
4  |GS1       |1        |8
5  |GS2       |2        |2
6  |ABC       |0        |2
7  |B123      |0        |2
8  |B423      |0        |2
9  |PTSD      |168      |2
10 |XCD       |0        |2
```

so when there's GS2 take value of eventData, otherwise cary value from previous testValueOpened

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite the logic a bit, as you cannot update each row 'one by one'. First check for HS2:

```
df.withColumn("testValveOpened", f.when(f.col("sourceName" == "GS2"), f.lit(1)).otherwise(0))
```

then do a cumulative sum and comparison to see if a GS2 was present before:

```
df.withColumn("testValveOpened", f.sum("testValveOpened").over(window) > 1)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, but it's not what I'm trying to achieve. I modified examples to make it clearer - your code albeit clever it will result in testValueOpened being boolean, whereas I want it to be numerical - being either it's previous value or current value of eventData
```

Comment: Okay, in that case, first calculate the sum (without >1): f.sum("testValveOpened").over(window) this creates groups, starting a new group at each GS2. Then, make each group the value of the first one: .withColumn("", f.first(eventdata).over(window.partitionby(testvalveopened).orderBy(ID))

Comment: Thanks ! Its more like I wanted it :),  I've attached it to [github](https://github.com/krystianorzechowski1/stackoverflow_questions/blob/main/pyspark_stackoverflow_nb.ipynb)
but I'm wondering on two things - can first value be 0? Also there are situations where sourceName ==GS2 and eventData ==0 but testValueOpened is not overwriten by newest value(in this case 0). I've attached jupyter notebook on my github